# Trim number function

Tags: c#, regex, trim

I need to trim the last portion of the string that contains the number.
In addition, I need to trim the part which does not start with the zero

This is what I am doing and I did not include the 0 since I am not sure how should I ignore it if the numbers starts with the zero.

```
        textBox13.Text = "A14C0681414010";
        //textBox13.Text = "A14C1381414010"; numbers will vary
        var first = textBox13.Text.TrimEnd("123456789".ToCharArray());
        var last = textBox13.Text.Substring(first.Length);
        // part 1 should contain A14C0
        // part 2 should contain 681414010
```

How can I achieve it? My function does not do it

Comment: Do you have more examples of what the input strings could be? It's hard to provide a (good) solution when given only a single example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's go through the regular expression step by step:

- start with a digit, but not zero: `[1-9]`
- followed by an arbitrary number of digits (including zero): `[0-9]*` (or abbreviated: `\d*`)
- followed by "the end of the line" (to get only the "last portion"): `$`.

  ```
  var input = "A14C0681414010"; 
  foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, "[1-9][0-9]*$")) {
      Console.WriteLine("Found: " + m.Value);
  }

  // Outputs "Found: 681414010"
  ```

Comment: +1 Great answer and explanation. However I would lose the foreach and assume that it will only match once or zero times.

Answer (score 0):

If there will always be a zero at the point you want to break you can find the position of that using `string.IndexOf()`. You can then break the string in to 2 substrings using that index.